# Where do I download Windows PowerShell v2 (2.0) RTM?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Is there a direct link to download Windows PowerShell v2 (2.0) RTM?

Google's first page of search results isn't helping, and I don't want to download the entire Windows Management Framework.

Comment: the management framework is what you need though; it's not as weighty as it sounds. You need both WinRM 2.0 and PowerShell 2.0; you can ignore the BITS 4.0 stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [PowerShell blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/pages/download-windows-powershell.aspx) and [TechNet Scripting with Windows PowerShell page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) both point [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929).

Comment: Thanks, wow how crazy is it that you can't find this download from Microsoft Downloads, MSDN or from their search.